# CPU fan spins crazy all the time (CPU temp is 35 °C)

Tags: speedfan

I have a Toshiba [Satellite u300](https://emea.dynabook.com/discontinued-products/satellite-u300-111/#) (old) laptop. As soon as I turn it on, its fan is going full blown all the time regardless of CPU usage. It's very strange and uncomfortable because of its noise.

I updated the BIOS and the problem is not fixed.

The CPU temp on idle state is around 35 °C, but still the fan spins fully.

There is no RPM in BIOS, and also the SPEEDFAN app of Windows doesn't show anything about fan or its RPM (yet it says "found Toshiba fan driver" when i run the app).

The problem persists in other environments without Windows.

What could be the reason and how can i solve this?

Comment: Could be a faulty sensor, or just that your fan firmware is somewhat corrupted. On my Lenovo laptop (bear with me, please), I use the "tpf-something" freeware you can find on this page (https://thinkwiki.de/TPFanControl), but at the bottom of the page, there's a variant called "ACFanControl", that's been developped for other brands than Lenovo. I haven't tested it myself, so I can't vouch for its usefulness or innocuity in any way, but it's worth a try. You can still monitor your temp with SpeedFan, ThrottleStop or any other tool, and make sure your PC isn't turning into a toaster.

Comment: i opened it up, some1 messed with the fan wiring and re-routed it to get direct 5v from usb ports of motherboard, i guess the fan controller chip on mobo was faulty so the previous repairman decided to do such a thing. thank you.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you sorted it out! Noisy fans are better than no fans at all, even in sports... ;-)